# Get the value of checkboxes in a specific section using javascipt

Tags: javascript

I have a page that contain different section these section appear when the user click on li an active class is added to the section and then this section appear
each section contain a box with checkboxes and a link to another page when i click on this link i should store the value of the checkboxes for the section active only to print them later

all the code work fine but my problem is that i only can have the checkbox value for the first section that contain active class by defaul

how can i solve that please?

```js
/*Put active class on li click for section*/
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li");
let tabsArray = Array.from(tabs);
let section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
let sectionArray = Array.from(section);

tabsArray.forEach((ele) => {
    ele.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        tabsArray.forEach((ele) => {
            ele.classList.remove("active");
        });
        e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
        sectionArray.forEach((sec) => {
            sec.classList.remove("active");
        });
        document.querySelector('#' + e.currentTarget.dataset.cont).classList.add("active");
    });
});

/*put the check box value in localstorage to print them later*/

let printBtn = document.querySelector(".active .btn-print");
let terms = document.querySelectorAll(".active input[type='checkbox']");
let termsValChecked = [];
let termsValUnChecked = [];

printBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    localStorage.removeItem("termschecked");
    localStorage.removeItem("termsunchecked");

    for (let i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
        if (terms[i].checked == true) {
            termsValChecked.push(terms[i].value);
        } else {
            termsValUnChecked.push(terms[i].value);
        }

    }
    window.localStorage.setItem("termschecked", JSON.stringify(termsValChecked));
    window.localStorage.setItem("termsunchecked", JSON.stringify(termsValUnChecked));
});
```

```css
.box {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

section {
display: none;
}

section.active {
display: block;
}

.nav {
list-style:none;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.nav li {
padding: 20px;
background-color: #ccc;
margin-left: 2px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
<li data-cont="r1">1</li>
<li data-cont="r2">2</li>
<li data-cont="r3">3</li>
</ul>

<section class="section section-one active" id="r1">
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<div class="box">
<input type="checkbox" value="test1">
<p>test1</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
<input type="checkbox" value="test2">
<p>test2</p>
</div>
<div class="print">
<a href="print.html?value=term" class="btn-print">Print</a>
</div>
</section>

<section class="section section-two" id="r2">
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<div class="box">
<input type="checkbox" value="test3">
<p>test3</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
<input type="checkbox" value="test4">
<p>test4</p>
</div>
<div class="print">
<a href="print.html?value=term" class="btn-print">Print</a>
</div>
</section>

<section class="section section-three" id="r3">
<h3>Section 3</h3>
<div class="box">
<input type="checkbox" value="test5">
<p>test5</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
<input type="checkbox" value="test6">
<p>test6</p>
</div>
<div class="print">
<a href="print.html?value=term" class="btn-print">Print</a>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You might just be able to change `let terms = document.querySelectorAll(".active input[type='checkbox']");` to `let terms = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");`

Comment: @asyncawait thank you for your reply but then how can i spesify the section when i click print i want only the value of checkboxes in the section active not all of them

Comment: You can put termsValChecked = [];
termsValUnChecked = []; inside the callback for the click. You have to move the array declaration before of the addEventListener too, otherwise the arrays won't be visible

Comment: I am looking over your code and finding a few bugs. Care if I re-write it instead of sticking to the layout you're using?

Comment: @asyncawait yes and if you can help me to solve the problem i did what you suggest i get all checkbox value not the value of the checkboxes in active section for example in the second section i have test 3 and test 4 when i click print i want to get only test 3 and test 4 not 1 2 5 and 6

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` returns a *static* `NodeList`, i.e. the list will reflect the state at invocation and won't update if the page later changes.

The following line runs *when you initialize* your page:

```js
let terms = document.querySelectorAll(".active input[type='checkbox']");
```

And that's why you always capture the first section in local storage.

You need to move this line inside your `click` handler so that you enumerate the checkboxes inside the `.active` section *at that time*.

Comment: let printBtn = document.querySelector(".active .terms .btn-print");
printBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    let terms = document.querySelectorAll(".active .terms input[type='checkbox']");
    let termsValChecked = [];
    let termsValUnChecked = []; i did it but still the same i get the calue of checkboxes of the section that contain active by default

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Attribute `".change"` from your selector on line 23

simply change

```
let terms = document.querySelectorAll(".active input[type='checkbox']");
```

to

```
let terms = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but when i did what you suggest i get all checkbox value not the value of the checkboxes in active section for example in the second section i have test 3 and test 4 when i click print i want to get only test 3 and test 4 not 1 2 5 and 6

Comment: tough one, let me check and get back to you

Comment: okay thank you i'm waiting thank you a lot